# Redirecting a path to the same container but different port with Traefik

Tags: traefik

I have the following setup with docker compose (running swarm mode):

```
mydomain.com --> ContainerA:8080
```

But what I would like is through labels, specify the following for the same container:

```
mydomain.com/test --> ContainerA:80
mydomain.com --> ContainerA:8080
```

So far I have the following Labels in compose:

```
deploy:
  labels:
    - traefik.port=8080
    - traefik.docker.network=apps
    - traefik.protocol=http
    - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Now I have tried with this, following your advice.Here is what I have set up, but still doesn't work, I get a 404 error:

`- traefik.docker.network=apps
 - traefik.main.protocol=http
 - traefik.main.port=8069
 - traefik.main.frontend.rule=Host:odoo.mydomain.com
 - traefik.worker.port=8072
 - traefik.worker.protocol=http
 - traefik.worker.frontend.rule=Host:odoo.mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrip:/longpolling`

Comment: did you solve this eventually? It looks to me like you need different host names like odoo.mydomain.com and worker.mydomain.com to be directed to different inner ports in the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bind multiple ports of a container, you have to use the `traefik.<service-name>.*` labels described here in the [documentation](http://docs.traefik.io/toml/#docker-backend).
For example,

```
deploy:
  labels:
    - traefik.first.port=80
    - traefik.first.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com;PathPrefixStrip:/test
    - traefik.second.port=8080
    - traefik.second.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But, what do you mean by <service-name> ? Do I have to put the name of the service ? I mean, the name that I give to the container when I do a docker service create?

Comment: Could that be related and that's why it doesn't work for me?https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/1321

Comment: Your choice! You have to give a name to your service.